# Blackberry Secure API

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Have had a look through some posts on this, can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Developing a java app for blackberry. Runs on simulator fine. Installed my three keys as all the instructions say. Right click on project, blackberry, sign with signature tool. It ask for a password which I provide. I then have another window open with four lines.

Two are signed, one by RIM Blackberry Apps API and one by RIM Crypto API - RIM.

The other two say not required and have signer IDs of 3 and RCI. Their status is not required, and Signer name says not signed with optional signer.

So it appears everything that needs to be signed is signed. Yet when I load project to device it says trying to access secure API.

Have I missed something blindingly obvious?

Comment: Did you allow all permissions to your application? You should set the permission for the application. Which version you are using? according to that you can give the permissions for an application in device; If you are using version 5.0 then, goto options--> applications-->select your application-->goto menu-->click on edit Permissions and allow all permissions and save. Then try to run the application; If you are using 6.0 version then goto options-->device-->applicationManagement-->select your application and do as above mention for 5.0;

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply sorry i've taken so long to reply! Tried this but no luck, still wont let me open the app.